# Cannot access sitecore.myget.org

Tags: nuget

This has been asked a few times, it's a "current problem" that will not be of long term use on SSE, but because of the number of duplicate questions I'm creating this as a community wiki.

At the time of writing, myget.org is experiencing a major outage. The workaround is in the answer below:

Answer (score 10):

Please see the following information from the KB article:

> Sitecore is moving its public feed from sitecore.myget.org to a different feed provider on November 30, 2023.
>
> - The URL of the new public feed is: https://nuget.sitecore.com/resources/v3/index.json
> - The URL for the internal artifact provider is: [https://cloudsmith.io/~sitecore/repos/resources/groups/](https://cloudsmith.io/%7Esitecore/repos/resources/groups/)
> - The custom NPM feed will move from https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery/sc-npm-packages to the public NPM provider https://www.npmjs.com/
>
> Both the original MyGet and the new public feeds are available now. After November 30, only the new NuGet and NPMJS public feeds will be available.
>
> Sitecore strongly recommends that all customers and partners update their CI/CD processes and build scripts to use the new public feeds as soon as possible to avoid interruptions beyond November 30, 2023.
>
> *Note:* Sitecore Experience Commerce, Content Hub, Sitecore PowerShell and Sitecore Installation Framework packages are not yet available through the public feeds. We will update this article as soon as they are available.

**Reference URL for latest updates:** https://sitecore.service-now.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002999

Rob Earlam created a blog post describing the ateps needed for updating an XM Cloud repo to the new feed: https://robearlam.com/blog/migrating-the-xm-cloud-introduction-repo-to-a-new-nuget-feed